# No Context Type was found automatic code-first migrations

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, visual-studio

I have a 'SampleSolution' that contains 2 projects namely SampleSolution.Model and SampleSolution.DataLayer. Under the 1st project is a class named "Orders" as below ,

```
public int SalesOrderId { get; set; }
public string CustomerName { get; set; }
```

But the "OrdersContext" class is within the 2nd project.
I have created the orders table from this Orders class using EF 6.1 and the database column for CustomerName reads -- nvarchar, null.

But I want to change it to 'not null'. So When I try to add some model validations, say I add the [Required] attribute to the CustomerName property of the 'Orders' class under proj1. But, When I run "enable-migrations -enableautomaticmigrations" under the PM Console and choose "SampleSolution.Model" it states **"NO CONTEXT TYPE WAS FOUND ...."** Please assist.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the migration needs to be created alongside the *context*, not the entity classes.

Comment: did you set the default project when migrating

Comment: Instead of choosing "SampleSolution.Model", choose "SampleSolution.DataLayer".

Comment: It worked.! Did what @Rob suggested. Chose SampleSolution.DataLayer. Thanks a ton.!!!!